# Logo has different height than menu nav CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put a logo next to the nav menu but it appears to be a different height. I've been trying adding margins paddings etc But I'm missing something. I'm starting to play with CSS so any help would be appreciated!

[image]

```css
.btn-header a{
    color:#999;
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    padding:10px 20px;
    font-size:12px;
    text-decoration:none;
    letter-spacing:2px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}

.btn-header .icon {
    display: none;
}

.btn-header a:hover{
    border:none;
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    background:#fff;
    padding:20px 20px; #000;
    color:#1b1b1b;
}

.btn-header  img{
    display: inline-block;
}
.footer{
    font-size:8px;
    color:#fff;
    clear:both;
    display:block;
    letter-spacing:5px;
    border:1px solid #fff;
    padding:5px;
    text-decoration:none;
    width:210px;
    margin:auto;
    margin-top:400px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header" class="btn-header">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50" height="50" width="50"/>
        <a href="#" >Como funciona</a>
        <a href="#" >Blog</a>
        <a href="#" >Tienda</a>
        <a href="#" >Trabaja con nosotros</a>
        <a href="#" >Reparar</a><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: No idea what you might've already tried, but you could try declaring `vertical-align: bottom` on the containing parent element `#header` - those elements should all be inline elements but the looks of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this css

```
#header{
display:flex;
align-items:center;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/41enzxpm/2/)

Answer (score 2):

just put `img {vertical-align:middle}` in the css and it should work...

If you want to set width and height for the image you have to set them in the img rule

```css
.btn-header a{
    color:#999;
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    padding:10px 20px;
    font-size:12px;
    text-decoration:none;
    letter-spacing:2px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
img {vertical-align:middle; width: 150px; height; 150px}

.btn-header .icon {
    display: none;
}

.btn-header a:hover{
    border:none;
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    background:#fff;
    padding:20px 20px; #000;
    color:#1b1b1b;
}

.btn-header  img{
    display: inline-block;
}
.footer{
    font-size:8px;
    color:#fff;
    clear:both;
    display:block;
    letter-spacing:5px;
    border:1px solid #fff;
    padding:5px;
    text-decoration:none;
    width:210px;
    margin:auto;
    margin-top:400px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header" class="btn-header">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50" height="50" width="50"/>
        <a href="#" >Como funciona</a>
        <a href="#" >Blog</a>
        <a href="#" >Tienda</a>
        <a href="#" >Trabaja con nosotros</a>
        <a href="#" >Reparar</a><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: it's overlaping with other list items

Comment: @Hamzaouiii Looks fine in "Full page" view

Comment: exactly! the page has to look fine in any view not only full page

Comment: @Hamzaouiii you're right, strictly speaking, in terms of good practices. But that's a responsive issue, not vertical-align issue - which OP's question concerns.

Answer (score 1):

Use table to the parent(.btn-header) and table cell and vertical-align :middle to child (.btn-header img, .btn-header a)

```css
.btn-header a{
    color:#999;
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    padding:10px 20px;
    font-size:12px;
    text-decoration:none;
    letter-spacing:2px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}

.btn-header .icon {
    display: none;
}

.btn-header a:hover{
    border:none;
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    background:#fff;
    padding:20px 20px; #000;
    color:#1b1b1b;
}
.btn-header { display: table;}
.btn-header  img{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.btn-header a {display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;}
.footer{
    font-size:8px;
    color:#fff;
    clear:both;
    display:block;
    letter-spacing:5px;
    border:1px solid #fff;
    padding:5px;
    text-decoration:none;
    width:210px;
    margin:auto;
    margin-top:400px;
}
```

```html
 <div id="header" class="btn-header">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50" height="50" width="50"/>
        <a href="#" >Como funciona</a>
        <a href="#" >Blog</a>
        <a href="#" >Tienda</a>
        <a href="#" >Trabaja con nosotros</a>
        <a href="#" >Reparar</a><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
    </div>
```